# SwiftUI button text centering

Tags: swiftui

I think I have a fairly simple question here. I would like for the text in the button to be centered. Here's what I have as well as a link to the image of the button.

```
Text("Button")
    .padding(.leading, 40)
    .padding(.trailing, 40)
    .padding(.top, 20)
    .padding(.trailing, 20)
    .background(Color.blue)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .cornerRadius(40)
```

[image: Misaligned button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify `.padding(.trailing, 40)` and `.padding(.trailing, 20)`. Change the last `trailing` to be `bottom`.

Try the following:

```
Text("Button")
    .padding(.leading, 40)
    .padding(.trailing, 40)
    .padding(.top, 20)
    .padding(.bottom, 20)
    .background(Color.blue)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .cornerRadius(40)
```

Since you specify `trailing` twice, the values (20 and 40) seem to be added, making the trailing-padding 60.
There is no bottom-padding specified at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using .background instead with a fixed frame, like so:

```
Text("Button")
.frame(width: 100, height: 32)
.foregroundColor(.white)
.background(Color.blue)
.cornerRadius(40)
```

[image]